# reagrupar valores de um array em novo array

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array de valores desse jeito:
`[{season:1, episode:1},{season:1, episode:2},{season:2, episode:1},{season:2, episode:2}]`

o que eu quero fazer é pegar a chave **season** e agrupar num array novo assim:

`{"season 1":[{episode:1},{episode:2}], "season 2":[{episode:1},{episode:2}]}`

como eu pego os valores de uma api, então não tem como eu definir "if season == 1", tenho que pegar essas seasons dinamicamente.

https://jsfiddle.net/xkqy8xqo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom não tenho muita certeza, mas, pelo layout feito está errado, porque dentro de cada elemento criado se tem um array de objetos, então, o layout seria mais ou menos assim:

```
{
  "season 1": [
    {
      "episode": 1
    },
    {
      "episode": 2
    }
  ],
  "season 2": [
    {
      "episode": 1
    },
    {
      "episode": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

então, para criar um novo layout de chave e valor se utilizou como referencia [Group By in Javascript](https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript) como base e com algumas modificações se tem a resposta acima:

```js
var items = [{
  season: 1,
  episode: 1
}, {
  season: 1,
  episode: 2
}, {
  season: 2,
  episode: 1
}, {
  season: 2,
  episode: 2
}];

Array.prototype.groupBy = function() {
  return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
    var keys = Object.keys(item);
    var val = keys[0] + ' ' + item['season'];
    groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
    var obj = {
      get [keys[1]]() {
        return item[keys[1]];
      }
    }
    groups[val].push(obj);
    return groups;
  }, {});
}

var news = items.groupBy();

console.log(news);
```

Simples

```js
var items = [{
  season: 1,
  episode: 1
}, {
  season: 1,
  episode: 2
}, {
  season: 2,
  episode: 1
}, {
  season: 2,
  episode: 2
}];

let groups = {};

for(let item in items)
{
  var name = 'season' + ' ' + items[item]['season'];
  if (groups[name] === undefined)
      groups[name] = [];
  var add = items[item];
  delete add['season'];
  groups[name].push(add);
}

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: obrigado pelo apontamento, ja editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma alternativa utilizando apenas um `for` e o objeto para as seasons. No `for` vai criando cada uma das chaves para as seasons caso não existam e depois adiciona cada episodio ao array de episódios da season.

```js
var episodes = [{
  season: 1,
  episode: 1,
  duration:53
}, {
  season: 1,
  episode: 2,
  duration:126
}, {
  season: 2,
  episode: 1,
  duration:119
}, {
  season: 2,
  episode: 2,
  duration:188
}];

let seasons = {};
episodes.forEach(e => {
  let key = `season ${e.season}`; //criar a chave de cada objeto
  if (!(key in seasons)){ //se ainda não existe cria o array de episódios
    seasons[key] = []; 
  }
  delete e["season"]; //remover a season na informação do episodio
  seasons[key].push(e); //adiciona todas as informações do episodio ao array
});

console.log(seasons);
```

Coloquei mais um atributo `duration` para tornar mais evidente que responde às necessidades que indicou de manter quaisquer outras informações do episódio.

Comment: só uma duvida, o **episode** que ta ai é apenas um exemplo, mas tem mais valores ali dentro, no seu exemplo ele faz push apenas de 1 valor

Comment: @Leandro O que está a dizer é que o objeto tem mais outras coisas para além do `episode` é isso ? Pode dar um exemplo mais concreto?

Comment: olha esse exemplo: http://bit.ly/2DPmpwS

Comment: @Leandro Certo, já editei a resposta para contemplar o resto das propriedades que o objeto possa ter